# How to configure material-ui theme on the fly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui

What would be the approach to configure the material-ui theme object on the fly?

That behavior is implemented when a user clicks on the button "set docs colors" on [the documentation page](https://material-ui.com/customization/color/#color-tool) of the mui.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [theme-provider](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#theme-provider) to create & provide the theme to your app. Basic code to create & provide theme is given below.

```
import { MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import App from './App';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#757ce8',
      main: '#3f50b5',
      dark: '#002884',
      contrastText: '#fff',
    },
    secondary: {
      light: '#ff7961',
      main: '#f44336',
      dark: '#ba000d',
      contrastText: '#000',
    },
  },
});

export default props => (
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <App {...props}/>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);
```

where App is your main app component.

if you have multiple themes then you have to maintain a state where you will define which theme you want to provide.

```
import { MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DarkTheme from './DarkTheme';
import LightTheme from './LightTheme';
import App from './App';

export default props => {
    const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(false);
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={darkTheme ? DarkTheme : LightTheme}>
            <App
                {...props}
                darkTheme={darkTheme}
                handleDarkThemeChanged={setDarkTheme}/>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
};
```

Comment: I am using the theme. I would like to change the theme at the run time

Comment: You can have a simple state in your component and can decide on the base of that which theme you want to provide. I've updated the answer to providing theme bases on state.

Comment: I'm new to react so sorry if this is obvious, but how would you call 'handleDarkThemeChanged' from within the App component?

Comment: you can add a Switch Button and on click of it trigger the function.